# Not create trigger using dbDelta() in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, triggers

I am trying to CREATE TRIGGER on custom table in mySQL db with dbDelta() function in wordpress plugin I am building!
On plugin activation, tables are created and populated with default data. When execute this function:

```
function PDFsem_initial_trigger($ldd_tabela) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.$ldd_tabela;

    //it works!!!
            $sql = "CREATE TRIGGER brisIspod BEFORE DELETE ON ".$table_name." FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO wp_ldd_usluga (usluga_naziv,usluga_rbr,seminar_id) VALUES('NEW TRIGGERED DATA', 2, 2)";
/*
    //dont work!!!
            $sql = "CREATE TRIGGER brisIspod BEFORE DELETE ON wp_ldd_seminar FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM wp_ldd_usluga WHERE wp_ldd_usluga.seminar_id = old.id_seminar;";
*/
            dbDelta( $sql );
    }
```

Function creates trigger on BEFORE DELETE ... INSERT INTO..., but wont create trigger on BEFORE DELETE ... DELETE... . If execute sql query in phpMysqlAdmin console directly trigger is created regularly.
I am not creating both triggers in same time so one is under comment. First trigger is just test sample. 
Is it possible to add trigger I want with dbDelta() in wordpress mySql db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger in mySql can be created with :

$sql = "CREATE TRIGGER brisIspod BEFORE DELETE ON wp_ldd_seminar FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM wp_ldd_usluga WHERE wp_ldd_usluga.seminar_id = old.id_seminar;";

**$wpdb->query**($sql);